# TimeDistributed layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, training-data

sorry I'm new to keras and RNN in general. I have these data on which to make training. Shape of `X_train=(n_steps=25, length_steps=3878, n_features=8)`, shape of `y_train=(n_steps=25, n_features=4)`. Basically for each step with length 3878 and 8 features I have one target of four. Now, I don't know how to train these data with a "temporal structure". Someone told me to use TimeDistributed layer, but I'm having issues with the shape. How can I use TimeDistributed on this?

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, TimeDistributed, SimpleRNN

modelSimple = Sequential()

modelSimple.add(SimpleRNN(200, return_sequences=True, activation='softmax'))
modelSimple.add(SimpleRNN(200, return_sequences=False, activation='softmax'))
modelSimple.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
modelSimple.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
modelSimple.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 7)
modelSimple.summary()
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what `n_steps` and `length_step` is with an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Because it is classfication, I don't think you might need to use `TimeDistributed` layer.**

However I can explain it to you, `TimeDistributed` allows you to apply the same operation on each time step. For instance, on a video, you may want to apply the same `Conv2D`on each frame. In the example in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed), you have 10 frames and you apply same convolution on each frame :

```
>>> inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10, 128, 128, 3))
>>> conv_2d_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))
>>> outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(conv_2d_layer)(inputs)
>>> outputs.shape

TensorShape([None, 10, 126, 126, 64])
```

In Time series, the core idea is the same : you may want to apply an operation on features of each time step. Because it is necessary to keep the time depandancy, you should set `return_sequences=True` before a `TimeDistributed` layer. For instance with your data :

```
modelSimple.add(SimpleRNN(200, return_sequences=True, activation='softmax',input_shape=(3878,8)))
modelSimple.add(SimpleRNN(200, return_sequences=True, activation='softmax'))
modelSimple.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(4, activation='softmax')))
```

gives you :

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
simple_rnn_15 (SimpleRNN)    (None, 3878, 200)         41800     
_________________________________________________________________
simple_rnn_16 (SimpleRNN)    (None, 3878, 200)         80200     
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_9 (TimeDist (None, 3878, 4)           804       
=================================================================
```

So you have a `Dense` layer which convert 200 features to 4. This conversion is repeated over all the `3878` time steps thanks to `TimeDistributed`.

**However, Keras is well created, and apply a `Dense` layer on a 2D object like `(num_steps x features)` will only affect the last dimension : `features`. As a result,
`Dense` layer, naturally process with `TimeDistributed` in most of Time Series.**

Comment: Thanks! But when I fit I have this ValueError: Shapes (None, 4) and (None, 3878, 4) are incompatible. 

`modelSimple.add(SimpleRNN(200, return_sequences=True,, activation='softmax',input_shape=(3878,8)))`
`modelSimple.add(SimpleRNN(200, return_sequences=True, activation='softmax'))`
`modelSimple.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(4, activation='softmax')))`
`modelSimple.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])`
`modelSimple.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 7)`
`modelSimple.summary()`

Comment: Yes it is a classification problem so the code I provided is not designed for your problem but as an example to explain how `TimeDistributed` works

Comment: Ok I got it, so I can't use Time Distributed with this problem right?

Comment: you can but you have to add : `modelSimple.add(Flatten())
modelSimple.add(Dense(4,activation='softmax'))`. It works but is probably not the best architecture.